# Can't save pickled MongoEngine document

Tags: python, mongodb, pickle, mongoengine

I have dumped some mongoengine documents into a pickle file. When I load them in runtime and I try to save them to Db, no error is raised but the documents are not saved.

Here is a code example:

```
    with open("documents.list", "rb") as infile:
        documents = pickle.load(infile)
        for document in documents:
            if MyDocument.objects(id=document.id).first() is None:
                document.save()
```

I have verified that the `document` object is associated with the correct collection and db. In the code above, it enters the `if` so `document.save()` is executed. But there are no documents in my collection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because your documents, when they were pickled, were already with a `saved` status, so they won't be inserted again in the Db. You can force their creation in the db by changing your `document.save()` line:

```
document.save(force_insert=True)
```